# Is "suggest a project" an acceptable question topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In my opinion my question applies to programming directly, but I can see why it might be closed, so I'm wondering if it's OK for Stack Overflow. Should it be posted on another site instead? Does anyone have suggestions for making it more precise?

> I really enjoy programming. I am basically the R&D department at work so every action I take involves at least 3 times as much research and learning as it does actual programming. This has lead to me not getting to use my favourite language (C++) in a few months.
>
> I am building an RPG game in c++ but I get frustrated with the lack of progress, a whole weeks work on battle algorithms and all people say when they see it is "is that all it does".
>
> So what I am looking for is a small to medium sized project. Something that would test my skills without needing hours of research into what is a Markov chain and other advanced concepts to complete.
>
> I was thinking of a simple game or interesting program. Last week I made a random word generator which I enjoyed until the hours of research into Markov chains :(
>
> Can anyone suggest some projects that would take a few days to finish that I could show people and be proud of?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Cody - not really, I'm sure that it (or something very like it) has already been asked. Plus it's very close to "what language should I learn next?".

Comment: Sort of relevant http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/15245/what-are-some-good-medium-sized-projects-an-inexperienced-programmer-could-take-o, and more relevant http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/suggestions-for-programs-to-develop-for-learning

Comment: @ChrisF: I find it slightly ironic that you say it's not a good question for PSE, and then note that something like it has probably already been asked. I'll be the first to admit I don't completely understand what's on topic there, but that makes it *especially* confusing. Anyway, I think this is different from "what language should I learn next". He's asking for specific suggestions and providing what seems to be a sufficiently contextualized scenario.

Comment: @Cody - The problem is that as stated the question is getting on for too localised. If it were generalised then it would be OK - but it would also be a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

Just to be clear:  **No**.  As per the [faq: What questions can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), there are four criteria:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- matters that are unique to the programming profession

as opposed to the [faq on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) where it *might* be on topic if you adjusted the wording a bit—see the comments above from ChrisF, one of the friendly moderators on Programmers.SE.

The fundamental problem with your question, though, is that it is really soliciting *opinions*; hence, it would be closed as off-topic on almost any site in the Stack Exchange network.

**Note:**  To address your specific question, you might consider trying to answer some of the existing questions on Stack Overflow tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (as there are quite a few...) and then, quite possibly, one of these answers could grow into a one or two day project.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good suggestion I will try it over the weekend